# Invoking startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() shows the location services icon always on the status bar

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm invoking startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges(), I have noticed this is making location services to run continuously which is making battery to consume more.

Following is my piece of code, this is not complete code.

```
class CurrentLocationController:UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    locationManager = delegate.locationManager
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    ...
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .Authorized {
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
    var update = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(location.coordinate, zoom: zoomSlider.value)
    mapView.moveCamera(update)
    saveLocation(location)
    }
}

func saveLocation2DB(location:CLLocation) {
   locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    ...
}
```

Is there any way that I need to get my App from background only when there is any significant location change and not consume battery a lot?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue call the deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable class method of the CLLocationManager class to determine whether the device supports deferred location updates.

Call the allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout: method ofthe CLLocationManager class to begin deferring location updates. To
prevent itself from calling the allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout: method multiple times, the delegate uses an internal property to track whether updates have already been deferred. It sets the property to YES in this method and sets it back to NO when deferred updates end.

Please see the sample code:

```
// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
// Add the new locations to the hike
[self.hike addLocations:locations];
// Defer updates until the user hikes a certain distance
// or when a certain amount of time has passed.
if (!self.deferringUpdates) {
CLLocationDistance distance = self.hike.goal - self.hike.distance;
NSTimeInterval time = [self.nextAudible timeIntervalSinceNow];
[locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance
timeout:time];
self.deferringUpdates = YES;
}
}
```

For more details, please read the page 19 of [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/LocationAwarenessPG.pdf) document.

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled is not working. It calls didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError but i am getting continuos location update!! Please tell me, what's wrong with it?